# batch file - running an installer that appends to the PATH and the running that new application from the bat

Tags: ruby, batch-file

I'm trying to setup a batch file that relies on "gem" which is a package manager for Ruby. Basically we want to run something like this:

```
gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0

if %errorlevel% == 9009 (
  rubyinstaller-2.5.1-2-x64.exe
  gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0
)
```

Basically if you don't have gem installed, the output is the following:

```
C:\workspace\3rdparty-svn\CucumberCpp>gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0
'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\workspace\3rdparty-svn\CucumberCpp>if 9009 == 9009 (
rubyinstaller-2.5.1-2-x64.exe
 gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0
)
'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\workspace\3rdparty-svn\CucumberCpp>pause
```

The if checks if gem exists, If it doesn't, Then we install ruby and then run gem again.
The problem is that this does not work because this is all run in the same instance of the command prompt and it doesn't seem to know about the new PATH which is set by the rubyinstaller.

Is there any way to do this with a batch file? Of course if I run the batch file again, Then gem is detected and it will be able to run the first command, and then of course skip the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Install Cucumber
2>nul gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0

if %errorlevel% neq 9009 (
    echo Cucumber install did not error code 9009.
    exit /b 0
)

rem Get Ruby path.
call :query_rubypath

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Installing Ruby.
    rubyinstaller-2.5.1-2-x64.exe /verysilent
    call :query_rubypath
)

rem Update PATH
if defined rubypath (
    if "%path:~-1%" == ";" (
        set "path=%path%%rubypath%\bin"
    ) else set "path=%path%;%rubypath%\bin"
) else (
    >&2 echo Ruby path not found.
    exit /b 1
)

rem Use command gem or command "%rubypath%\bin\gem"
@rem "%rubypath%\bin\gem" install cucumber -v 2.4.0
gem install cucumber -v 2.4.0

if %errorlevel% == 9009 (
    >&2 echo Cucumber error code 9009.
    exit /b 1
)

exit /b

:query_rubypath
rem Get Ruby path from registry
set "rubypath="

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in ('
 reg query HKCU\Software\RubyInstaller\MRI\2.5.1
 /v InstallLocation
 2^>nul
') do if /i "%%~A" == "InstallLocation" set "rubypath=%%~C"

if not defined rubypath exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

The installer `rubyinstaller-2.5.1-2-x64.exe` is compiled with
`Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (u)`.

The installation can be handled by [Setup Command Line Parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

By default, components `ruby` is selected and `msys2` is deselected.
If reinstalled, the installer will read the uninstall entries
to determine the state of the installed components to select
if no `/COMPONENTS` parameter is specified.

If unattended install, you can use for example:

```
rubyinstaller-2.5.1-2-x64.exe /verysilent /COMPONENTS="ruby,msys2"
```

The `/COMPONENTS` parameter is optional.

The PATH envirionmental variable is updated with:

> C:\Ruby25-x64\bin

This would be the default install path on the `%systemdrive%`.
The script will locate the actual path from the registry.

Important registry keys located are:

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RubyInstaller\MRI\2.5.1
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\RubyInstaller-2.5-x64-mingw32_is1
> ```

The code of `call :query_rubypath` will get the install path of Ruby.
The variable named `rubypath` will store the value if defined.

How *Ruby* is installed is a preference as you mention.
Either way, the script will handle much of the basic handling.

- The script will will locate the install path so
  that the `gem` command can be executed.
- Ruby will be installed if the install path is not found.

If you want Ruby installed even if the install path is found,
then remove the `if errorlevel 1` condition. Make changes as
needed for your environment.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the path to gem, the user can choose to install it wherever they please

Comment: The updated answer has a script with code to get the install path from the registry. This may solve the path issue with the command `gem`.

Comment: perfect! all I had to do was to also add \bin to the rubypath for it to be able to find gem :) thanks a lot!